# Web application and mobile application

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, jruby

I want to ask if im using ruby on rails for my web application, what language should I make mobile version(or custom mobile version) of the accordingly my web application?? I need to use JRuby or ?? use Java instead? what is the suggestion that can be combine this two that work together?

Comment: Do you mean a mobile capable site? Or a Mobile Native Application?

Comment: I don't understand; if your web app is in RoR, wouldn't your web version also be in RoR but with different layouts and/or CSS and/or etc?

Comment: The question is not understandable as it is, could you express it more clearly ? thx, citraL

Comment: hmm,it is mobile capable site,can receive realtime. Dave: you mean the mobile version??  Actually ,what I mean is , I planning to build a web system to manage the company employee, then this system is syn with mobile too. so, i wonder, what technology should I use in order to build this kind of web application and mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use the classical "HTML mobile web app", the answer is this:

You should ship **HTML-only** to the users. All communication between the mobile app and the servers should be via an API (JSON is a decent choice for the API protocol, and it's easy to implement in Rails).

You can create the HTML in any way you please - e.g. by compiling .erb/.haml templates in rails.
But on the finished app, you should optimally only have index.html, styles.css and scripts.js.

You can ship an html web app via [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com)

Comment: but what i want is realtime @@ I can actually build this web application using ROR and mobile version is using JAVA? or any suggestion? (can see above my comment to see cleary what i want to build)